# FontAwesome 5 - $fa-font-path not taken into account

Tags: sass, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, parceljs

My FontAwesome icons won't work because the `$fa-font-path` variable is not taken into account while building my `fontawesome.scss` file.

**Step 1: I installed FontAwesome 5.13 via npm**

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save
```

**Step 2: I edited my /scss/vendors.scss file and added the following**

```
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
```

These seems to be the right paths, as if I make any changes I'm getting an error during the build.

**Step 3: I re-built my vendor.css**

```
./node_modules/.bin/parcel build scss/vendor.scss --no-source-maps --out-dir public/css --out-file bundle.css
```

Inside it seems that `/` is used instead of `$fa-font-path` value.

[image: vendor.css]

**Step 4: I tried to set `$fa-font-path` value in `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/_variables.scss`**

Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to resolve this issue.

It was due to **parcel**, which by default sets `/` instead of `./` as the default public path for CSS files. There's quite a lot of people complaining about this behavior as well as [issues referenced in their Github repo](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/323).

**SOLUTION**

Add the following parameter to your build script:

```
--public-url ./
```

Example:

```
parcel build src/index.html -d public --public-url ./
```

More details in [Parcel's Documentation](https://parceljs.org/cli.html).